# Рендер интерфейса Delphi поверх того того, что отрендерил opengl

Tags: delphi, opengl

Мне нужно рисовать интерфейс прям на том что отрисовал OpenGl. Для этого после рендеринга OpenGL я делаю примерно следуюшее:

```
Button3.Repaint;
```

Естественно с включенной двойной буфферизацией. Всё работает, но некоторые кнопки по дизайну я делаю как TImage и тогда, даже с включённой двойной буфферизацией компонент мерцает, что логично, но как это можно исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как это исправить, у меня даже нет предположений, на редеринг кнопок с помощью OpenGL и времени нет (курсач горит) и желания, так что может есть возможность какогото костылька?) Дизайн кнопок будет довольно простым, так что если реднерить их чуть оптимизированнее, то проблем быть особо и не должно